# python's lib pymysql stop replying randomly

Tags: python, mysql

I am using pyMysql for saving data to mysql db. I have permanent flow of tick data from financial market. i use cur.executemany for inserting 10 lines by one time. It worked fine just for first 20-30 lines - then it stops write it and don't throw any exception..

```
self.queue.append((timestamp,side,size,price))
    if len(self.queue)>=10:
        try:
            self.logger.info("Writing 10 lines to sql..")
            conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='*****', db='sys')
            cur = conn.cursor()
            sqlQ=""" INSERT den_trades (date2 , side, size, price) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
            cur.executemany(sqlQ, self.queue)
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()
            self.queue=[]
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.warning("Exception while cur.executemany... sys.exc_info()[0]: {}".format(sys.exc_info()[0]))
            self.logger.warning("e.message ".format(e.message))
            template = "An exception of type {0} occurred. Arguments:\n{1!r}"
            message = template.format(type(e).__name__, e.args)
            self.logger.warning(message)
            conn.rollback()
```

i am trying to get some exceptions - but no one warning..

strange thing is - when problem appears - "Writing 10 lines to sql.." still work fine for every tick - self.queue continue to grow up - so  self.queue=[] never happens.. how can it be? first string of try: block still work, but last string stop occur.. if so - there should be any exception... right?

one more thing. i have another script that's running fine on same machine. that script saving 1000 lines by one time through pyMysql. 
Can it be a problem?

Comment: Please, somebody help me!

Comment: I tried run this script alone.. tried use another sql connector/lib [link] (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation-binary.html) but it still dont write to MySql ... (((